# VBA nesting for each for PDF

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I am having a problem in this output. It seems to mostly working but I am missing a step somewhere.

In the below code:
K4 to K7 is number codes and l4 to l7 is some word names - 4 records
Im trying to output this to PDF and it should only have 4 records however for some reason it outputs repeated versions, 16 in total. I know the loops are wrong. Anyway to fix this?

```
Sub foreachtest2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c As Range
Dim f As Range



Sheets("Lookup Table").Range("K4:K7").Name = "Rng"
Sheets("Lookup Table").Range("L4:L7").Name = "RngName"


For Each c In Range("Rng")
    For Each f In Range("RngName")

    Sheets("Site Report").Select
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = c.Value




Sheets("Site Report").Select
 Range("A1:M78").Select
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\path" & f.Value & c.Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

Next
Next


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need two loops, just one to iterate on the `K` column. At each iteration you retrieve the corresponding value in `L` by using ``Offset.

```
For Each c In Range("Rng")
    Set f  = c.Offset(, 1)
    ' ...
    ' do the work. I cant verify if the code inside your loop
    ' does the intended work. But this quick fix should solve the
    ' 16 values issue. Now you should have only 4 records to work on. 
Next
```

Comment: It does as you describe perfectly, using offset did work as I needed it to. I didn't need the other for, as you suggested. Much appreciated.